# parsing different xml files with python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml, elementtree

I have 2 xml files,
word and topic.

I need to parse the word files based on the topic file.
Files as below

file 1 topic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<nite:root nite:id="ES2002a.topic" 
xmlns:nite="http://nite.sourceforge.net/">
<topic nite:id="ES2002a.topic.vkaraisk.1" other_description="introduction of participants and their roles">
      <nite:pointer role="scenario_topic_type"  href="default-topics.xml#id(top.4)"/>
      <nite:child href="ES2002a.B.words.xml#id(ES2002a.B.words0)..id(ES2002a.B.words5)"/>
      <nite:child href="ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words0)..id(ES2002a.D.words3)"/>
      <nite:child
```

File 2 word (ES2002a.B.words.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<nite:root nite:id="ES2002a.B.words" xmlns:nite="http://nite.sourceforge.net/">
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.B.words0" starttime="50.42" endtime="50.99">Okay</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.B.words1" starttime="50.99" endtime="50.99" punc="true">.</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.B.words2" starttime="53.56" endtime="53.96">Right</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.B.words3" starttime="53.96" endtime="53.96" punc="true">.</w>
   <vocalsound nite:id="ES2002a.B.words4" starttime="55.415" endtime="55.415" type="other"/>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.B.words5" starttime="55.98" endtime="56.53">Um</w>
```

File 2 word (ES2002a.D.words.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<nite:root nite:id="ES2002a.D.words" xmlns:nite="http://nite.sourceforge.net/">
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words0" starttime="67.21" endtime="67.45">Mm-hmm</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words1" starttime="67.45" endtime="67.45" punc="true">.</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words2" starttime="74.89" endtime="75.24">Great</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words3" starttime="75.24" endtime="75.24" punc="true">.</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words4" starttime="82.08" endtime="82.25">And</w>
   <w nite:id="ES2002a.D.words5" starttime="82.25" endtime="82.43">I&#39;m</w>
```

There are multiple word files that need to be parsed based on the topic file.

```
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.B.words.xml#id(ES2002a.B.words0)..id(ES2002a.B.words5)"/>
```

we see that the topic file is saying get words 1-5 from file ES2002a.B.words

the desired output is
Okay . Right . Um 
m-hmm . Great

I have parsed in the topic file, although the code is clunky

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("./ES2013a.topic.xml") 
root = tree.getroot() 
childA = []
elementT = []
ElementA = []
for child in root:
    elementT.append(str(child.tag))
    ElementA.append(str(child.attrib))
    childA.append(str(child.attrib))
    for element in child:
        elementT.append(str(element.tag))
        #childA.append(child.attrib)
        ElementA.append(str(element.attrib))
        childA.append(str(child.attrib))
        for sub in element:
            #print('***', child.attrib , ':' , element.tag, ':' , element.attrib, '***')
            #childA.append(child.attrib)
            elementT.append(str(sub.tag))
            ElementA.append(str(sub.attrib))
            childA.append(str(child.attrib))

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c'] = np.array (childA)
df['t'] = np.array(ElementA)
df['a'] = np.array(elementT)

file = df['t'].str.extract(r'([A-Z][A-Z].*[words.xml])#')
start = df['t'].str.extract(r'words([0-9]+)')
stop = df['t'].str.extract(r'.*words([0-9]+)')
tags = df['a'].str.extract(r'.*([topic]|[pointer]|[child])')
rootTopic = df['c'].str.extract(r'ES2013a.topic.rdhillon.(\d+)')
df['f'] = file
df['start'] = start
df['stop'] = stop
df['tags'] = tags
# c= topic
# r = pointerr
# d= child
df['topicID'] = rootTopic

df = df.iloc[:,3:]
```

I am thinking of getting a lit of the word files used and then iterating over the word file based on the start and stop conditions

Comment: The question is unclear. You have tagged the question with "beautifulsoup", "lxml", and "elementree", but you have not shown us any code. What have you tried?

Comment: @mzjn i will add what i have tried to the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once used [jxmlease](https://github.com/Juniper/jxmlease) to parse the xml. It simply converts the XML string into python `dictionary`.

topic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<nite:root nite:id="ES2002a.topic" 
xmlns:nite="http://nite.sourceforge.net/">
<topic nite:id="ES2002a.topic.vkaraisk.1" other_description="introduction of participants and their roles">
      <nite:pointer role="scenario_topic_type"  href="default-topics.xml#id(top.4)"/>
      <nite:child href="ES2002a.B.words.xml#id(ES2002a.B.words0)..id(ES2002a.B.words5)"/>
      <nite:child href="ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words0)..id(ES2002a.D.words3)"/>
</topic>
</nite:root>




import jxmlease

with open('topic.xml') as topic:
    topic_content = topic.read()

root = jxmlease.parse(topic_content)
first_word_selection = root['nite:root']['topic']['nite:child'][0].get_xml_attr("href")

print(first_word_selection)
output : ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words0)..id(ES2002a.D.words3)
```

Comment: Hi Sijan. I justr tried running that code and i got  the following errorTypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Hi @Pythonuser, I have added my `topic.xml` content above. Can you run that once? I is working fine at my end.

Comment: Hi @Sijan Bhandari, i ran the xml file, using the content and got the following error: KeyError: 'nite:root'

Comment: You have installed `jxmlease` right? You can try to print `root` variable and look whether it is parsing well or not.